# Swift 3 - Reload NavigationController Button Image

Tags: swift, image, refresh, uibarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I have a navigation controller view, with an embedded collectionview controller. I have a right bar button added programmatically, with an image added to it as follows:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "greyCircle").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (handleGrayCircleButton))
```

I would like a user that clicks on this button, to be able to change the image from grey to silver. I have the button handler set up to switch from grey to silver with each press:

```
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "greyCircle")
```

However, the image only changes briefly before switching back. I have tried to save the color of the image as a 'flag' variable, i.e. if it is currently grey, turn to silver, in order to make the change persist, however, the image continually resets to whatever it is loaded with (either with viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear).

Is there anyway to refresh/reload the navigationController tab bar after each click and make it persist, along with the images for the bar buttons?

#

EDIT: Following is full button handler.

```
   func handleFavoritePress(){
        print("Favorites pressed")
        if(!returnTrueIfInFavorites(objectName: readString(object: self.patientRecord!, key: "name"), objectType: LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)){
            // Add to favorites
            Favorites_Names.append(readString(object: self.patientRecord!, key: "name"))
            Favorites_Types.append(LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)


            // Let user know
            let patientName = readString(object: self.patientRecord!, key: "name")
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "\(patientName) has been added to your favorites.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                rootViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first
            }
            if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                rootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
            }
            rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "savedFavorite_1")

        }else{

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "favorite_2")
            deleteFromFavorites(objectName: readString(object: patientRecord!, key: "name"), objectType: LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)
        }
        for favorite in Favorites_Names{
            print("Favorites are currently: \(patient)")
        }

    }
```

And other functions:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        collectionView?.backgroundView = setBackgroundImage(imageName: "whiteBackground")
        navigationItem.title = "Patient"
        if(returnTrueIfInFavorites(objectName: readString(object: patientRecord!, key: "name"), objectType: LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)){
            setupNavBarButtonsIsFavorited()
        }else{
            setupNavBarButtonsNotFavorited()
        }
    }

    func setupNavBarButtonsNotFavorited(){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favorite_2").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (handleFavoritePress))
    }
    func setupNavBarButtonsIsFavorited(){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "savedFavorite_1").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (handleFavoritePress))
    }
```

Comment: You mean, after you update the image, it somehow get set back in, say, few seconds?

Comment: Yes, it switches to the new image, briefly then right back. If I switch tabs, then back, it displays correctly, but not while still inside the same collectionviewcontroller tab

Comment: Can you show us code of your full button click handler please?

Comment: Added the button handler

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies within this two `LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients`, `returnTrueIfInFavorites` or the `patientRecord` variable.

Either `LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients` did not get updated on your function `handleFavoritePress`'s code

```
/* this code */
Favorites_Names.append(readString(object: self.patientRecord!, key: "name"))
Favorites_Types.append(LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)
/* this code */
```

Because from what you've explained in the comments section, if I understood it correctly, is that when you **tap** the button the image changes, and then you navigate to a different view, but then when you navigate back, `viewDidAppear(_:)` and `viewWillAppear(_:)` will be triggered.

Which in the code block below I will explain

```
// this function will be triggered everytime you navigate into this view (because it has appeared)
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    /* don't forget to call super.viewWillAppear(true) */
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    /* don't forget to call super.viewWillAppear(true) */

    collectionView?.backgroundView = setBackgroundImage(imageName: "whiteBackground")

    navigationItem.title = "Patient"

    // the problem lies here
    /* the function `(returnTrueIfInFavorites(objectName: readString(object: patientRecord!, key: "name"), objectType: LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients))` is always returning one thing which is why your image returns back to its previous state */ 
    if (returnTrueIfInFavorites(objectName: readString(object: patientRecord!, key: "name"), objectType: LIST_CoreDataBaseObjects.Patients)) {
        setupNavBarButtonsIsFavorited() // only one of these gets called
    } else {
        setupNavBarButtonsNotFavorited() // only one of these gets called
    }
}

func setupNavBarButtonsNotFavorited() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "favorite_2").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (handleFavoritePress))
}

func setupNavBarButtonsIsFavorited() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "savedFavorite_1").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (handleFavoritePress))
}
```

All of these or you're just not updating the variable `self.patientRecord!`'s value (I haven't seen any setting in your code relating to this variable)

Comment: Navigating back and forth from one tab to the other produces the proper change to the image; its clicking the button inside the current tabView that doesn't produce the change. viewWillAppear is triggered on these tab transitions-- I am looking for a way to trigger the navigationBar while still in the current view.

Comment: Ok. where is your function `handleGrayCircleButton` please show it on the question.